# Get child item in Json without knowing the itemname

Tags: javascript, json, github, get

I have an answer like this:

```
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/47d8d5c3e80bc1568bda",
      "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/47d8d5c3e80bc1568bda/forks",
      "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/47d8d5c3e80bc1568bda/commits",
      "id": "47d8d5c3e80bc1568bda",
      "git_pull_url": "https://gist.github.com/47d8d5c3e80bc1568bda.git",
      "git_push_url": "https://gist.github.com/47d8d5c3e80bc1568bda.git",
      "html_url": "https://gist.github.com/47d8d5c3e80bc1568bda",
      "files": {
        "fileWhatever": {
          "filename": "fileWhatever",
          "type": "text/plain",
          "language": null,
          "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/test/47d8d5c3e80bc1568bda/raw/21aefad8f2f7aea0556360ff3a40a557b793e330/fileWhatever",
          "size": 19,
          "truncated": false,
          "content": "this is the content"
        }
      }
....
```

The thing is that I want to take the value of "content". I can do it like this:

```
data.files.fileWhatever.content
```

but I'm not supposed to know the name of the file so 'fileWhatever' could be anything. How can I jump one level to get the content of any file?

I'm doing this with javascript

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that one solution - though might not be an elegant one would be to traverse through the keys in any depth.

That is - the pseudo should be like -

```
find-value-by-key(key-name, json):
     for(key:json)
          if key==key-name
              return content of key
          else if key has children
              find-key(key-name, json.key-name)
```

There probably should be some technical way to extract the value

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but:

```
var thefilename = "";
var thetype = "";
//etc...
for(var n in a.files)
{
    for(var fn in a.files[n])
    {
        if(fn=="filename")
            thefilename=a.files[n][fn];
        if(fn=="type")
            thetype=a.files[n][fn];
    }
}
document.write("<div>" + thefilename + "</div>");
document.write("<div>" + thetype + "</div>");
```